# handlebars.js path context in helper method

Tags: javascript, handlebars.js

I have a handlebar helper function registered as follows:

```
Handlebars.registerHelper('link', function(text, url){
   return text + url; //whatever, return something
});
```

Now, if I call it like so, it works.

```
{{{link "hello" "localhost" }}} //works
```

but If I pass in a variable that has a path in it, it fails

```
{{{link "hello" ../url}}} //the second argument becomes undefined
```

Is this a bug with Handlebars?

Comment: Maybe `{{{link "hello" "../url"}}}`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it's working for me in beta4: http://jsfiddle.net/mgcross/GMrnz/34/ Is the 'url' key you're referencing nested?

Comment: Thanks, it turns out I didn't need this, but its good to know that it works.